# List Sub query Columns

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

If I needs to list `TAB3` columns in the output. How do I do it

```
select *
    from tab2 T2 right join
         tab1 T1
         on T1.MemNo = T2.MemId
    where exists (SELECT 1
                  FROM TAB3 x
                  WHERE x.Col1 =  T1.SID AND x.Col2 = T2.SVID ) and
          T2.MemId IS NULL
```

Sample Data

```
Tab1

MemNo   SID

116537  S110
116537  D011
575777  D012
214438  S110
434611  D114
214438  D011
208368  D012
208368  S110

TAB2

MemID   SVID

116537  110
116537  11
214438  11
434675  114
214438  110
575788  12
208368  12
208368  110


TAB3

Col1    Col2

D011    11
S110    110
D114    114
D012    12
```

Expected Results

```
MemNo   Col2

575777  12
434611  114
```

Thax

Comment: How about showing some sample data and expected output?

Comment: @Ramblin, Sample data was added. Sorry I missed that earlier

Comment: So, you want to get those memids from tab1, which are not present in tab2. And then get the col2 value from tab3. Correct?

Comment: Exactly.. That's what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should inner join tab1 and tab3 and make sure that tab1.memno is not present in tab2.

```
select tab1.memno, tab3.col2
  from tab1 
 inner join tab3
    on tab1.sid = tab3.col1
 where not exists (select 1 from tab2
                   where tab2.memid = tab1.memno);
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e7ee6/6).

Answer (score 3):

Simple as that:

```
select
*
from
tab1 t1
inner join tab3 t3 on t1.SID = t3.Col1
left join tab2 t2 on t1.MemNo = t2.MemID
where t2.MemID is null
```

It gives correct result. See it live in an [sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ed97/2/0).

The inner join on tab3 checks, that the entry in tab3 exists, with the left join / is null you make sure, that the entry in tab2 doesn't. Joins most of the time give a better performance than subqueries / IN () / EXISTS ().

Comment: Thanks mate. Good stuff

Comment: How do we do the change in case if we want to find out unmatched or missing records in `TAB3 `

Comment: Simply by left joining and checking with is null. Here's an excellent explanation of joins: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html